# mongoDB mongoose - callbacks

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm having a hard time understanding why my callback excutes but doesn't return the value. the data.itemId is console logged but it seems like the avatar.itemId isn't being returned. Are you not able to return values of the newly created doc? Pretty sure I'm just doing it wrong. I've read [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) but I'm still unsure of where the callback is returned to or why no data is being returned from the saveAvatarImage call.

```
const Image = require("../model/Image");

const saveAvatarImage = async (uploadImage, id) => {
  const fs = require("fs");
  //Set image data
  let options = { upsert: true, new: true, omitUndefined: true };
  let update = {
    timestamp: Date.now(),
    img: {
      data: fs.readFileSync(uploadImage.filepath),
      contentType: uploadImage.mimetype,
    },
  };
  let filter = { itemId: id };
  let callback = function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log(data.itemId);
    return data.itemId;
  };
  //Create image in db
  let avatar = await Image.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, options, callback);
  return avatar.itemId;
};

module.exports = { saveAvatarImage };
```

this works

```
busboy.on("finish", async function () {
    //check for upload
    if (isEmptyObj(uploadImage))
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "Something went wrong." });
    //if image is for profile
    if (formValues.type === "avatar") {
      //////save image to database
      // saveAvatarImage(uploadImage, id);
      //Set image data
      let options = { upsert: true, new: true, omitUndefined: true };
      let update = {
        timestamp: Date.now(),
        img: {
          data: fs.readFileSync(uploadImage.filepath),
          contentType: uploadImage.mimetype,
        },
      };
      let filter = { itemId: req.user._id };
      //Create image in db
      const avatar = await Image.findOneAndUpdate(
        filter,
        update,
        options,
        function (err, data) {
          if (err) console.log(err);
          console.log(data);
        }
      );
      return res.json(avatar);
    }
  });
```

i want to do this. (solved)

```
busboy.on("finish", async function () {
    //check for upload
    if (isEmptyObj(uploadImage))
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "Something went wrong." });
    //if image is for profile
    if (formValues.type === "avatar") {
      //////save image to database
      let avatar = await saveAvatarImage(uploadImage, req.user._id);
      
      return res.json(avatar);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your callback, try:

```
let callback = function (err, data) {
    if (!err && data) return data;
    
    else console.log(err ? err : "Data not defined");
  }
```

I'd assume you should be returning the entire `data` object and then doing `avatar.itemId` after the `await`, as you currently are.

Comment: i was able to get it to work after i added await to the function call. not sure if thats what you meant but thank you!